# How to append value at the top of rect

Tags: d3.js

I have made a vertical bar chart and have the following to append the text onto the bars.
 If i set y attribute as 0,the text is shown at the top, irrespective of the length of bars i.e all values stick together on top even though bar length is 50,1,1,3.
 What i need is that the value should display at the immediate top of the bar.
I tried text anchor end also but it didnt work.

```
  sets.append("text")
                .attr("class", "global")
                //.attr("y", function(d) {
                 //   return yScale(d.global) ;
               // })
                .attr("dy", 5)
                .attr("dx",(xScale.rangeBand() / 4))
                .attr("font-family", "sans-serif") 
                .attr("font-size", "14px")
                .attr("fill", "black")
                .text(function(d) {
                    return ( commaFormat(d.global) > 0) ? commaFormat(d.global) : "";
                });
```

here is the rect code

```
 sets.append("rect")
                .attr("class","global")
                .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand()/2)
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return yScale((d.global/total)*100);
                })
                .attr("height", function(d){
                    return h - yScale((d.global/total)*100);
                })
                .attr('fill', function (d, i) {
                return color(d.global);
                }) 
                .append("text")
                .text(function(d) {
                    return commaFormat((d.global/total)*100);
                })
                //.attr('x', function(d, i) {
                //  return xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
                //})
                //.attr('y', function(d) {
                //  return h - yScale((d.global/total)*100) + 14;
                //})
                .attr("font-family", "sans-serif") 
                .attr("font-size", "11px")
```

Comment: changed yscale to " yScale((d.global/total)*100)" works okish. If there's any other solution,pass it on.

Comment: could you make a fiddle with the complete code and data?